# How to write the output of scriptnames into a file?

Tags: vimscript, ex-mode

`:scriptnames` can list all plugins installed in my vim.
How to write the output of scriptnames into a file?

```
:scriptnames > names.txt
```

It can't do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this can be done with `redir >names.txt|silent scriptnames|redir END`

I'm using `silent` here to avoid a **-- more --** -prompt.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to list them in a buffer, there is

```
:new
:put=execute('scriptnames')
```

If you need to search, well, there is `filter()`

```
:echo filter(split(execute('scriptnames'), "\n"), 'v:val =~ "syntax"')
```